# python pandas dataframe merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge some dataframe from csv files using for loop in python. But the result is empty. Why is that so? Here is my code.

```
result = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['col_A', 'col_B'])
for i in range(0, 5):
    #col_A is integer for numbering, col_B is float in range 0 to 1
    temp = pandas.DataFrame([[0, 0.5132443], [1, 0.12436421], [2, 0.12341162]], columns = ['col_A', 'col_B'])
    result.merge(temp)
print(result) #result is empty dataframe
```

Comment: Have you verified `temp` is actually assigned to a dataframe after running?

Comment: This code, and this code alone, runs without error?

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Comment: yes, temp is actually assigned and remains after for loop.
And code is run without any error

Comment: The challenge I am having understanding this, is that `result` is not defined, and thus `result.merge` should cause an error.  Where is result defined?

Comment: oh sorry, I changed some variable's name when I copied the code, but I made a mistake. Now it is modified. 'normal' -> 'result'

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result of the merge:

```
result = result.merge(temp)
```

From the ([DOCS](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

> Returns:
>
> merged : DataFrame
>
> The output type will the be same as ‘left’, if it is a subclass of DataFrame.